# consulta Mongodb traer varios registros solo pasando el nombre

Tags: mongodb

Tengo esta estructura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si mediante una consulta podría traer todos los productos que haya, osea: poner 'Cesar' y me traiga todos los productos. ¿Y como seria?

Comment: la respuesta es si, esa es la idea de este tipo de base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás pidiendo una top-level property (en este caso "`p_nombre`") es tan simple como hacer

```
db.restaurants.find( { "p_nombre": "cesar" } )
```

Este es simplemente un `equality operator`